# Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать форму с полями <input> в цикле foreach и дальше передать их через POST для записи в MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать форму с полями  в цикле foreach и дальше передать их через POST для записи в MySQL

```
form action="urp1.php" method="post" <br>
    foreach ($st as $item) 
    td input name='_какую переменную здесь?__' /td
```

Затем, как принять её в `$_POST['_а какая переменная здесь?_']`

И, наконец, как указать её в запросе к БД MySQL:

```
query("INSERT INTO ... VALUES($_POST['_и здесь какая переменная?'])
```

Спасибо.

Comment: нам ничего не понятно

Comment: стало понятнее совсем ничего

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <form action="urp1.php" method="post"> foreach ($st as $item) <td><input name='_какую переменную здесь?__'> .    Затем в $_POST['_а какая переменная здесь?_']       И, наконец, в запросе к БД MySQL  query("INSERT INTO ... VALUES($_POST['_и здесь какая переменная?'])

Comment: Прочитай, пожалуйста, справку и оформь вопрос как подобается (его можно редактировать)

Comment: Вы так и не прочитали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .... потому что на данный момент всё так же ничего не ясно......что в `$st`. одинаковые по функции данные (например имена пользователей) или нет (массив с данными пользователей включая логин, имя, дата регистрация и пр).....какие данные ожидаются на сервере......какого вида должны быть итоговый запрос insert..... что именно туда вставляются...опять же только тупо список имён или несколько разных колонок......в общем, если не постараетесь полноценно, как разумный человек, умеющий рассуждать, описать, то ответа вы не дождётесь

Comment: Алексей, с огромным уважением к Вам, но все же не стоит создавать лишних сущностей. Вопрос нулевого уровня?  Вы совершенно правы. значит , и ответ допустим "нулевого" уровня. Даже желателен именно "нулевого". ну какие данные может хотеть вставлять человек такого уровня? вряд ли  объекты в формате JSON. Интересовало именно то, каким способом, в виде цикла, создать ряд переменных для их использования в форме (<form>). Благодарю ответившего по существу 4 kilograms.

Comment: Вы хотите быть хорошим разработчиком или каким попало? Если второе - согласен, ответ подходит и удачи вам. Если первоее - то ответ очень вредный и в дальнейшем вас же самого засмеют и просто на работу не пустят. Вы не хотите сделать сразу всё правильно? даже **на нулевом уровне**? А это было вполне возможно, но более грамотно. Но дело ваше. Принимать вредные советы, за которые вас же потом засмеют.  Т.к. ответ вредный - ему минус.

Comment: А раз **вы** не захотели нормально осветить весь вопрос и проблему - видимо вы и правда не хотите делать всё хорошо, даже с начального уровня ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, как вариант можно циклом (например for) создать 5 инпутов, в каждом сгенерировать уникальный name)

```
for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    echo "<input name='example_<?php $i ?>'>";
}
```

ну а в обработчике встретить:

```
$name_1 = $_POST['name_1'];
$name_2 = $_POST['name_2'];
$name_3 = $_POST['name_3'];
$name_4 = $_POST['name_4'];
$name_5 = $_POST['name_5'];
```

Comment: Ужасное решение. Для новичков 0-го уровня пойдёт, но остальные этот код засмеют

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну, какой вопрос, такой ответ :) Учитывая что автор вопроса так и не объяснил что именно за переменные хотят передаваться

Comment: Если автор ничего не объяснил, то на какой вопрос ты давал ответ?

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ.